# WCF REST service basic authentication with multiple users

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf, rest

I have a WCF REST service with basic authentication. I need a setup where different clients will send credentials assigned to them, while making requests. So I need to allow authentication for multiple users. To avoid custom authentication for each user, I was thing about adding as many users I need in the system; so for all those users, authentication will be done automatically.

From what I read, there is no limit of adding max number of users in the system. But is it possible that large number of concurrent requests (each having different user credentials) will work? or is there a limit in such case.

Also is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve the configuration you described, but you should be aware that there seems to be an internal issue with WCF Rest and Basic Authentication, which is described in the following link:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/531787/self-hosted-wcf-rest-with-http-basic-authentication

As a result, you may want to follow the guidance of an established solution, such as documented in the following blog post:
http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2012/06/restful-services-authenticating-clients.html